# JSON data through perl issue

Tags: json, perl

I have an issue when I try to execute a loop to handle a json file,
I am trying to replace the Zero in "correct":0 to the right answer number tagged by {C} for example for Question 1 I need to put "correct":1 and for Question 2 I need to put "correct":3 and so on ...

this is my perl file :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
use utf8;

use JSON;

my $json;
{
  local $/; #Enable 'slurp' mode
  open my $fh, "<", "test.json";
  $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
my $data = decode_json($json);
# Output to screen one of the values read
my $var = $data->{'question'}->{'answers'};
my ($correctans) = grep {s/.*(\d).*/$1/ if m/C/} (my @answers = qw($var));
# Modify the value, and write the output file as json
$data->{'question'}->{'correct'}->[0] = $correctans;
open my $fh, ">", "test.json";
print $fh encode_json($data);
close $fh;
```

my json file :

```
{
    "introduction":"This quiz tests you about foo and goo", 
    "questions":[
        {"question":"Why is the sky blue?", 
         "answers":["Unicorns{C}","Fairies","Boring Science","Kittens"],
         "correct":0},
        {"question":"Why are kittens so cute?", 
         "answers":["Magic","Fur","Meow{C}","More Kittens!"],
         "correct":0}
    ]
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use JSON;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $json = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $data = decode_json($json);

for my $questions (@{$data->{questions}}) {
    my $answers = $questions->{answers};
    my ($answer) = grep {$answers->[$_] =~ /\{C\}/} (0..$#$answers);
    $questions->{correct} = 1 + $answer;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;

__DATA__
{
    "introduction":"This quiz tests you about foo and goo", 
    "questions":[
        {"question":"Why is the sky blue?", 
         "answers":["Unicorns{C}","Fairies","Boring Science","Kittens"],
         "correct":0},
        {"question":"Why are kittens so cute?", 
         "answers":["Magic","Fur","Meow{C}","More Kittens!"],
         "correct":0}
    ]
}
```

Outputs

```
{
  introduction => "This quiz tests you about foo and goo",
  questions    => [
                    {
                      answers  => ["Unicorns{C}", "Fairies", "Boring Science", "Kittens"],
                      correct  => 1,
                      question => "Why is the sky blue?",
                    },
                    {
                      answers  => ["Magic", "Fur", "Meow{C}", "More Kittens!"],
                      correct  => 3,
                      question => "Why are kittens so cute?",
                    },
                  ],
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Miler , but how can use DATA from a file.json and save OUTPUT to output.json ?

Comment: Your code already demonstrates how to load data from a file and send it back when done processing.  That part looked fine.  You just needed help with how to process the parsed data structure, which this demonstrates.

Comment: @Miller++ cool cross platform object/ref accessing! @saad+- (grep my answer...) your question made far more sense when you posted examples. However your attempt to paste code relating to another given example to solve your un-shown problem did make me chuckle.